# How to auto-upload all images in Gmail attachments to Google Photos

Tags: gmail, google-photos

I was hoping there was a way to crawl the entire history of my Gmail account, and automatically upload any attached images to my Google Photos account for backup purposes.  What is the easiest way of going about doing this?

Comment: i'd guess you would want to set up a pop3 email client on your desktop to "download" all emails, install google photos uploader and configure it to scan the email folder. not sure if it would work without any tweaking, might depend on which client you choose. however, if you want to do that "for backup purposes", i wonder why not backing up the whole email and thus instead of bothering with google photos just do the pop3 email backup, add a auto forward to a secondary unrelated gmail you'd create just for backup and set a few backup solutions on your desktop.

Comment: Because I want all the photos to be scanned by Google Photos so I can search by keyword to detect objects and such